# Read CSV file then split the values and create a global variable

Tags: powershell

Trying to read a file that having comma delimited rows.  I want to read each row and split into array and make a global variables with the array values.

File content:

```
server1,component1,service1
server2,BatchProcessor2,service2
server3,BatchProcessor3,service3
```

I want to create a global variable as a directory path like below while reading each row.

```
$deployment.path = D:\server1\component1\service1
$deployment.path = D:\server2\component2\service2
$deployment.path = D:\server3\component3\service3
```

But I get null values.

Code:

```
$fileIn  = 'D:\Test\build.properties.dev'
(Import-Csv -Path $filein -Delimiter ',' -Header 'ServerName','ComponentName','ServiceName' | ForEach-Object {
    $deployment.path = D:\$_.ServerName\$_.ComponentName\$_.ServiceName
    if (!(Test-Path $deployment.path)) {
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $deployment.path
    }
})
```

Comment: where does `$Deployment` come from? you are assigning a value t. a prop of that $Var, but i don't see where it comes from ...

Comment: also, why is your pipeline enclosed in parens? that seems unneeded ...

Comment: also also ... where you do `get null values`?

Comment: Did this work for you?

Comment: @Avinash Hi there, will you kindly accept my answer below as it seemed to solve your problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Do it like this:

```
$csv = Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\build.properties.dev'

$csv | ForEach-Object {
    $path = "D:\$($_.servername)\$($_.componentname)\$($_.servicename)"
    if (!(Test-Path $path)) {
        New-Item -Itemtype Directory -Path $path -Confirm:$false -Force
    }
}
```

If your .csv does not have headers, add them. If you can’t, do it programmatically. You could use `Tee-Object`, for example. Same principle above applies.

Comment: on my win7ps5.1 setup, the `New-Item` cmdlet requires the `-Force` parameter to make the full path. have you tested your code to make sure that it will build the whole path if it is not there?

Comment: I did not test on Windows 7. If a command I used has a requirement on Windows 7, add that parameter. I wrote this on a Chromebook on StackOverflow. No Powershell available at the time. I believe this will work. I did add the -Force parameter above.

Comment: kool! i _think_ it is still required for multi-level path creation on all OSs. thanks for adding that parameter! [*grin*]

Comment: I tested this. I did not need -Force. WMF 5.1, Windows 1803.

Comment: thank you for the feedback ... i appreciate the info! [*grin*]